# Titles for a table

Tags: tables

I'm pretty much a beginner with LaTeX, and I've only ever used LaTeX to do homework assignments for my Prob & Stats and Physics courses. My formatting has been slowly improving each week, as I'm trying to learn more useful commands. Now, I want to recreate a table that my professor has in this weeks problem set. [image: Professor's table for reference]

I currently have in my document the following code:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}
    {|m{.75cm}|m{.75cm}|m{.75cm}|m{.75cm}|m{.75cm}|m{.75cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{$\mathbf{Toilet \ Paper}$}\\
        \hline
        & $\mathbf{0}$ & $\mathbf{1}$ & $\mathbf{2}$ & $\mathbf{3}$ \\
        \hline
        $\mathbf{0}$ &  0.31 & 0.22 & 0.09 & 0.04\\
        \hline
        $\mathbf{1}$ & 0.15 & 0.05 & 0.04 & 0.01\\
        \hline
        $\mathbf{2}$ & 0.04 & 0.03 & 0.01 & 0.01\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I want to be able to shorten the row containing the "Toilet Paper" columns title so that it doesn't include the leftmost column. I also want to add "Wipes" for the rows title, similar to the "W" in the reference picture. Any ideas? I believe it's important to note that in the typed code, I'm using the longtable, array, and amsmath packages.

EDIT: This is my first post. I'm open to suggestions on how to format, or what else to include in these types of questions. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Hello and welcome! As a new member myself I've come to learn that a compilable [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) is of uttermost importance when raising questions as document class and/or package conflicts may interfere with the outcome. It also helps others to immediately [recreate your problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/why-does-tex-require-such-elaborate-mwes) on their setup and thus provide more direct and useful answers. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using the new package `tabularray`. With it, the table customizing is very easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={cQ[c,m,.75cm]Q[c,m,.75cm]Q[c,m,.75cm]Q[c,m,.75cm]Q[c,m,.75cm]}, 
        row{1-2} = {font=\bfseries},
        column{1-2} = {font=\bfseries},
        vline{2} = {3-5}{solid},
        vline{3-7} = {2-5}{solid},
        abovesep=4pt}
        & &\SetCell[c=4]{c}{\bfseries Toilet  Paper}\\
        \cline{3-6}
        & & 0 & 1&2 &3 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        \SetCell[r=3]{c}Wipes& 0 &  0.31 & 0.22 & 0.09 & 0.04\\
        \cline{2-6}
        & 1 & 0.15 & 0.05 & 0.04 & 0.01\\
        \cline{2-6}
        & 2 & 0.04 & 0.03 & 0.01 & 0.01\\
        \cline{2-6}
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses (a) an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment (to save myself from having to use lots of `$` symbols to initiate and terminate inline math mode) and (b) uses the `w` column type instead of the `m` column type. I made the latter choice as no automatic line breaks would appear to be needed.

[image]

(I leave it as an exercise to the reader to replace `\textbf{T}` with `\textbf{To...}` and `\textbf{W}` with `\textbf{Wi...}`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for w column type 
% two handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand{\blank}{\multicolumn{1}{c}{}}   
\newcommand{\blankx}{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}}

\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
% your prof actually seems to have used "\setlength\extrarowheight{8pt}"
\begin{array}{ c | c | *{4}{wc{7.5mm}|} }
   \blank & \blank  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{T}}\\
   \cline{3-6}
   \blank & \blankx & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} \\
   \cline{2-6}
              & \mathbf{0} & 0.31 & 0.22 & 0.09 & 0.04\\
   \cline{2-6}
   \textbf{W} & \mathbf{1} & 0.15 & 0.05 & 0.04 & 0.01\\
   \cline{2-6}
              & \mathbf{2} & 0.04 & 0.03 & 0.01 & 0.01\\
   \cline{2-6}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In that environment, the key `hvlines` draws all the rules, excepted in the "exterior" rows and columns (specified by the keys `first-row` and `first-col`) and in the empty corners (when the key `corners` is used).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \begin{NiceTabular}
      [first-row,first-col,hvlines,corners,columns-width=auto]
      {>{\bfseries}ccccc}
        & &\Block{1-4}{\bfseries Toilet  Paper}\\
        & & \RowStyle{\bfseries} 0 & 1 & 2 &3 \\
        & 0 &  0.31 & 0.22 & 0.09 & 0.04\\
        \bfseries Wipes & 1 & 0.15 & 0.05 & 0.04 & 0.01\\
        & 2 & 0.04 & 0.03 & 0.01 & 0.01\\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]